# Android/IOS develpopment: how can i reduce my app size in store

Tags: android, ios

I have an app in Play/Apple Store that contains too many resources such as audio/video files, images .. etc.

The Size of Resources is now approximately 2 GB which is the maximum allowed in the Store.

My Application is multilingual and each Language needs Video, Audio and Image files attached.

Now after seven languages in the Application i can not add a new language because after that will not be able to upload the app to the Store.

is there a solution ???

thanks..

Comment: Store your files on a server, one first launch of your app have the user select which languages they want and have the app download those files.

Comment: Exactly that, I do not want to bloat my device with italian, chinese, french and russian videos, audiofiles, etc. while I only use german+english.

Answer (score 0):

On-demand resources with hosting either on apple's servers or your own (the API allows this). Still, I recommend inspecting your media files, it may happen that changing format, resolution, etc., can save some space. Even with ODR, downloading gigs of data for some app is not a good user experience and maybe quite cumbersome for mobile networks. You might detect the device you are using, locale, language, etc., and download ODR only for this particular device. Most of the users don't change language at all. This way you can download only 2GB/7 = ~285+ MB and in most of cases only once.